# MongoDB running out of disk space

Tags: java, mongodb, bigdata

I have to store around **200GB** of raw data in one MongoDB collection. Which works fine. 
After I inserted all objects, I have to iterate over the whole collection with a cursor and write some new fields on every object. 
But then at some point an error is raised saying:

**com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't take a write lock while out of disk space**

```
com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't take a write lock while out of disk space
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:100)
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:134)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:130)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:154)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:137)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.update(DBApiLayer.java:353)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:165)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:771)
at com.asuum.products.mongodb.ProductDatabaseHandler.writeToProductsDB(ProductDatabaseHandler.java:98)
at com.asuum.products.images.ImageSizeCalculator.convertImages(ImageSizeCalculator.java:89)
at com.asuum.products.images.ImageSizeCalculator.main(ImageSizeCalculator.java:100)
```

I'm using the Java-Client, MongoDB version 2.4.6 and I'm running it on a huge 64bit Linux server with 32 cores, 256GB RAM and 1.5 TB disk space.

When I run stats it tells me:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , 
  "ns" : "products.productCollection" , 
  "count" : 2090339 , 
  "size" : 2.6235131E9 , 
  "avgObjSize" : 1255.0658529549514 , 
  "storageSize" : 6.933086208E9 , 
  "numExtents" : 25 , 
  "nindexes" : 0 , 
  "lastExtentSize" : 726470656 , 
  "paddingFactor" : 1.9980000000199927 , 
  "systemFlags" : 0 , "userFlags" : 0 , 
  "totalIndexSize" : 0 , "indexSizes" : { } , 
  "ok" : 1.0 }
```

So there is enough disk space I suppose...

I'm running the compact-command on the collection on program startup. 
I didn't change anything in the default configuration regarding nodes and replica sets.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Was that stat run without a size parameter? Also have you checked the OS' actual space?

Comment: I used the stats comand like that: mongodb.coll.getStats() and I have more than one TB free disk space.

Comment: Saskia,
I'd like to see a little more information on this to get a full picture. Please run db.stats() from within the 'products' database itself and forward the output. Can you also please provide output of the 'df' command on the server, and of the 'mount' command, as well as the full command you use to run the mongod server, and the dbpath. Finally, please also provide the error(s) seen in the mongod.log.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I solved the problem. The data was stored on a really small partition with only 18G. I changed dbpath to a partition with a larger drive and now it should work :)